# Arangodb change default foxx service path

Tags: api, nginx, path, arangodb, foxx

Hi everyone Does anybody know how to change the path of a defined foxx service. 
I would like to have something like "IP/login" and "IP/register".
 By default it is accessible under "_db/..." path.
The only way I found was to use a Webserver Like nginx to rewrite or restrict incoming URL paths. Is there a better solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm Alan from the ArangoDB Foxx team.

If you want to expose your service to the wild, a reverse proxy like nginx or Apache is absolutely the best way to go. Keep in mind that if you allow users to talk to ArangoDB directly you're also likely exposing the HTTP API and the admin interface -- these are probably not things you want on the public web.

There's currently no way to mount a Foxx service at the "root" URL and this is unlikely to change.